# Why is my c3.js pie graph not rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, data-visualization, c3.js

This is javascript code in html script tags for a pie chart that I have taken directly from the samples on c3.js. It doesn't appear on the page. Why doesn't it work? I don't have much experience in coding and even less in javascript specifically, please help me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/c3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/js/c3.js"></script>
    <script>
      var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
          columns: [
            ["versicolor", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5,
                           1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2,
                           1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6,
                           1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3,
                           1.1, 1.3],
            ["virginica", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9,
                          2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8,
                          2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3,
                          2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0,
                          2.3, 1.8],
            ["setosa", 30],
          ],
          type : 'pie',
          onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i, this); },
          onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i, this); },
          onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i, this); },
        },
        axis: {
          x: {
            label: 'Sepal.Width'
          },
          y: {
            label: 'Petal.Width'
          }
        }
      });

      setTimeout(function () {
        chart.load({
          columns: [
            ["setosa", 130],
          ]
        });
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function () {
        chart.unload({
          ids: 'virginica'
        });
      }, 2000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: None of the javascript will appear on the webpage. I tested with putting text in the body tag and that appeared, only the javascript will not.

Comment: It can't work, you are generating the chart object but not attaching it so the page. Go back to the example and copy that verbatim.

Comment: if you inspect the div id 'chart' it may need to set the height there or in the svg element

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I would like to offer a solution for those looking into this later on. You are loading D3 from a cdn while loading c3 from a relative path. You might need to set the window.onload event to your websites logic so it will wait to run until everything is loaded

```
function init(event){
  //execute code to run after everything is done loading
};
window.onload = init;
```